# How to get first record as parent after its child records?

Tags: sql-server-2012

Ex:

```
   Id    ParentId
      ----  ----------
       0    NULL
       1     0
       2     0
       3     1
       4     1
       5     2
       6     2
```

I want get this as following format:

```
 Id    ParentId
----  ----------
 0     NULL
 1     0
 3     1
 4     1
 2     0
 5     2
 6     2
```

Comment: Its not clear as to what you are trying to achieve, what is the logic you are trying to implement. You need to add more details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Have a look at `HIERARCHYID`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx

Comment: Hi Venkatesh, as you are new to SO, please be aware, that the professionals giving answers here, are hungry for reputation points. Please go through the answers and vote them up if they are helpful. If one of them helped you to solve your problem, you should mark it as the accepted answer, Thx!

Answer (score 0):

There is no "easy" way to traverse such a self-joined list down to any depth and find its implicit sort order.

You could try something like this. Or you have a look on HierarchyID (as commented). This is made for this kind of relationship...

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Id INT,ParentId INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (0,NULL)
,(1,0)
,(2,0)
,(3,1)
,(4,1)
,(5,2)
,(6,2);

SELECT TopNode.Id AS TopNode,Child1.Id AS Child1,Child2.Id AS Child2  
FROM @tbl AS TopNode
OUTER APPLY(SELECT Id FROM @tbl WHERE ParentId = TopNode.Id  ) AS Child1
OUTER APPLY(SELECT Id FROM @tbl WHERE ParentId = Child1.Id  ) AS Child2
WHERE TopNode.ParentId IS NULL
```

This comes back with

```
0   1   3
0   1   4
0   2   5
0   2   6
```